# Specifying a different input type for a Pydantic model field (comma-separated string input as a list of strings)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

Using Pydantic, how can I specify an attribute that has an input type different from its actual type?

For example I have a `systems` field that contains a list of systems (so a list of strings) and the user can provide this systems list as a comma separated string (e.g. `"system1,system2"`); then I use a validator to split this string into a list of strings.

The code below is doing that and it's working but the type hinting is wrong as the systems field is actually a list of strings, not a string; the validator is splitting the original string into a list of strings.

How can I fix this?

```py
import typing

from pydantic import BaseSettings, Field, validator


class Config(BaseSettings):
    systems: str = Field([], description="list of systems as a comma separated list (e.g. 'sys1,sys2')")

    @validator("systems")
    def set_systems(cls, v) -> typing.List[str]:
        if v == "":
            return []
        systems = list(filter(None, v.split(",")))
        return systems


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Config(**{"systems": "foo,bar"})
    print(c)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Always annotate model fields with the types you *actually want* in your schema!**

If you want the field `systems` to be a list of strings, then annotate it accordingly. A comma-separated string is the *exception* after all. To allow it, use a [`pre=True` validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) to intercept that string before the default field validators get to it (and raise an error). Then you can split it and return the list as you wish:

```py
from pydantic import BaseSettings, Field, validator


class Config(BaseSettings):
    systems: list[str] = Field(default_factory=list)

    @validator("systems", pre=True)
    def split_comma_separated(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, str):
            v = v.strip()
            return [] if v == "" else v.split(",")
        return v


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(Config.parse_obj({"systems": "foo,bar"}))
    print(Config.parse_obj({"systems": ""}))
    print(Config())
```

Output:

```
systems=['foo', 'bar']
systems=[]
systems=[]
```

Answer (score 1):

For Pydantic v2 and `pydantic-settings`, you need to define a custom settings source class, e.g.

```py
class CustomSettingsSource(EnvSettingsSource):
    def prepare_field_value(
        self, field_name: str, field: FieldInfo, value: Any, value_is_complex: bool
    ) -> Any:
        # allow comma-separated list parsing
        if field_name == "systems":
            return value.split(",") if value else None

        return super().prepare_field_value(field_name, field, value, value_is_complex)
```

and add it to your settings with a `settings_customise_sources` class method:

```py
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    systems: list[str] = []

    @classmethod
    def settings_customise_sources(
        cls, settings_cls, init_settings, env_settings, dotenv_settings, file_secret_settings
    ):
        return (
            init_settings,
            CustomSettingsSource(settings_cls),
            dotenv_settings,
            file_secret_settings,
        )
```

https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/pydantic_settings/#parsing-environment-variable-values